# Title keeps shifting into the navigation bar(Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I have a navigation bar, and I have some text goes in front of the image directly below the nav bar above it.This image is responsive, so it scales depending on the size of the screen. However, when I adjust the screen to its smallest size(i.e the size that it would be if it were on a mobile device) the image stays in one place, but the text that would normally be fixed in front of the image pushes upward, behind the navigation bar. Can you please help explain why this is? Here's my code.

HTML

```
<header>
    <!--Navigation Secton-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Anna's Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"> About</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Talk To Me</a></li>        
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>   
    <!-- Top Image, Title Text-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <img class="image img img-responsive" src="http://www.qerja.com/journal/wp-content/uploads/CODING.jpg">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Anna's Portfolio</h1>
            <h2>Come Inside.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--About, Mission-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="about">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <p>My name is Anna Gibson and I'm a web developer<br> who seeks to tell the stories of the marginalized.<br> I'm a staunch advocate for those who struggle with<br> their mental health and I hope that I can create apps<br> that will help people with their mental health as apps<br> have helped me. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
    position:relative;
    bottom:70px;
    text-align:right;  
}

.image {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:0;
    height:200px;
}

.text {
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    bottom:400px;
    color:white; 
    font-family:;
    font-size:24px;    
}
```

Thanks so much, if anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Text pushes behind navbar because of bottom:400px; issue on `.text` class

You Need Some HTML and CSS Fixes

HTML

```
<header>
<!--Navigation Secton-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Anna Portfolio</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"> About</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Talk To Me</a></li>        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>   
    <!-- Top Image, Title Text-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="main-section">
                <img class="image img img-responsive" src="http://www.qerja.com/journal/wp-content/uploads/CODING.jpg">
                <div class="text">
                    <h1>Anna's Portfolio</h1>
                    <h2>Come Inside.</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--About, Mission-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="about">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
                <p>My name is Anna Gibson and I'm a web developer<br> who seeks to tell the stories of the marginalized.<br> I'm a staunch advocate for those who struggle with<br> their mental health and I hope that I can create apps<br> that will help people with their mental health as apps<br> have helped me. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-brand {
position:relative;
bottom:70px;
text-align:right;  
}

.main-section{
  position: relative;
}

.image {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:0;
    height:200px;
}

.text {
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
color:white; 
font-family:;
font-size:24px;   
left:0;
right:0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin:auto;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/bfp0z1r5/8/)

Hope this Helps..